# Faster iteration over thousands of files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, glob

I'm trying to do something on ~200,000 files in a single folder.

When I do this:

```
for i in *; do /bin/echo -n "."; done
```

One dot is printed every few seconds. The same operation on a folder with a hundred files works blazingly fast.

Why is this so? How to accelerate the process for folders with thousands of files?

Comment: create a thread process to do that in time

Comment: The bottleneck is probably your file system, rather than the shell. If you can  create a temporary ramdisk with `btrfs` and move the files there (or just symlinks?) you might get better performance. And of course, first remove any obvious complications (Windows mount? NFS? FUSE?)

Comment: It is a rather powerful Linux with NFS, but I think you are right the filesystem slows this. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-is-the-most-high-performance-linux-filesystem-for-storing-a-lot-of-small-fi

Comment: You're starting a new process every time you call `/bin/echo`. Use the shell built-in `echo` instead, or the `printf` built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with GNU find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "."
```

Comment: Good idea, and it worked. My "print a dot" was a simplification for clarity sake, but actually I used xargs and did a more advanced operation on the files.